# System.Printing namespace set printer page source

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, system.printing, pdftron

I am trying to print XPS stream through `System.Printing` namespace

```
    Stream stm = pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXps(pdfdoc);

    LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
    PrintQueueCollection pqc = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues();
    PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(_PrinterName);
    MemoryStream ms = defaultPrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml();


    // Call AddJob
    System.Printing.PrintTicket printTicket = defaultPrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;


    PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob();

    Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;//may be this line is wrong, can you suggest alternative?
    myStream = stm;//may be this line is wrong, can you suggest alternative?
    myStream.Close();//may be this line is wrong, can you suggest alternative?
    var inp= defaultPrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities().InputBinCapability;
    System.Printing.PrintTicket newprintTicket = XpsPrinterUtils.ModifyPrintTicket(printTicket, "psk:JobInputBin", "NS0000:" + _PaperSource);
    System.Printing.ValidationResult vr = defaultPrintQueue.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket(printTicket, newprintTicket);// this line giving exception while changing page source merge and validate
    myPrintJob.Commit();
```

[XpsPrinterUtils.ModifyPrintTicket from github](https://github.com/serbrech/wpfprintengine/blob/master/SUT.PrintEngine/Utils/XpsPrinterUtils.cs)

The code is not working and I am stuck with this.

Anyone has good idea or solution to this to print (Xps file stream obtained by pdftron) using system.printing namespace and change page source dynamically.

Comment: `myPrintJob.JobStream = stm;` instead of your 3 lines from `Stream myStream` till `myStream.Close();` that is atleast 1 error I can quickly spot

Comment: @SynerCoder yes may be wrong those line but i tried a lot and change code too much time..so...you can understand...code may be wrong/change that i obtained from source.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test, but this would appear to be closer to the correct solution.

```
Stream stream_source = pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToXps(pdfdoc);
Stream stream_sink = myPrintJob.JobStream;
stream_source.CopyTo(stream_sink);
```

You might want to test the above out, by creating stream_sink as a stream to a file on disk, and verifying that stream_source.CopyTo(stream_sink) works as expected. If so, then any remaining issue would be with using the System.Printing API, and not something with PDFNet.